# Coda 2 Mountain Lion git

Tags: git, coda, osx-mountain-lion

I just upgraded to the new OS X Mountain Lion and git is not working anymore in Coda 2. It works ok in the Xcode and in the Source Tree (git GUI client I am using).

I updated git to the latest version, but it did not solve my problem.

Terminal:

```
git --version
git version 1.7.11.3
which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

So the version of git is the one I updated for and the path for the git is correct (this path is used for Coda 2 in settings as well).

In the Coda 2 in the site settings SourceControl switch is OFF. When I turn in ON save and open setting window again it will be OFF.

Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. Now it's working.
All you need to do is to install Command Line Tools in Xcode (you can do that in Xcode preferences). Hooray.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue except when I type which git I get /usr/local/git/bin/git. If anyone has ideas, it would be much appreciated.

I tried changing my $PATH, but no luck.

UPDATED:  Just follow these instructions...

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/mountain-lion-git-fix/

Worked for me.